# In what way can a method provide better estimated than another method that already provides unbiased estimates?

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, robust-standard-error

I read in Rand Wilcox's (2010) book:

> "If homogeneity of variance cannot be assumed (with regard to regression), although the method of least squares still provides you with unbiased estimates of parameters (in this case, b1), you can obtain better estimates using other methods, such as weighted least squares"

My question is, if you are already obtaining an unbiased parameter, how is it that weighted least squares can improve on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be more unbiased than unbiased, right. But maybe you can find weights so that the resulting estimator has smaller variance i.e. higher precision with all its benefits like smaller confidence intervals and stronger inference.

Same bias but smaller variance will provide an estimator with smaller mean squared error (= bias squared + variance).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Michael M. Would I then be correct in assuming that the benefits of this higher precision would be felt in more accurate probability values? That was the idea I got from your reply.

Comment: If you consider two-sided p values, then those derived from the more efficient estimator would be closer to 0 (because standard errors are smaller). That does not necessarily mean that the p values are less *inaccurate*, just smaller.

Comment: Hello Michael M, thank you very much for taking the time to provide this information, I really appreciate it. Have a nice day.